# Add number to set

Tags: python, set

What am I doing wrong here?

```
a = set().add(1)
print a # Prints `None`
```

I'm trying to add the number `1` to the empty set.

Comment: @CharlesB If you are giving an answer, then you should do so in an answer. Please note it's horribly unpythonic to use semicolons. Python is meant to be readable, and putting multiple statements on a single line is very bad for readability.

Comment: @GarethLatty: he is not answering the question, either.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It is a convention in Python that methods that mutate sequences return `None`.

Consider:

```
>>> a_list = [3, 2, 1]
>>> print a_list.sort()
None
>>> a_list
[1, 2, 3]

>>> a_dict = {}
>>> print a_dict.__setitem__('a', 1)
None
>>> a_dict
{'a': 1}

>>> a_set = set()
>>> print a_set.add(1)
None
>>> a_set
set([1])
```

Some may consider this convention "a horrible misdesign in Python", but the Design and History FAQ [gives the reasoning](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list) behind this design decision (with respect to lists):

> **Why doesn’t `list.sort(`) return the sorted list?**
>
> In situations where performance matters, making a copy of the list
>   just to sort it would be wasteful. Therefore, `list.sort()` sorts the
>   list in place. In order to remind you of that fact, it does not return
>   the sorted list. This way, you won’t be fooled into accidentally
>   overwriting a list when you need a sorted copy but also need to keep
>   the unsorted version around.
>
> In Python 2.4 a new built-in function – `sorted()` – has been added.
>   This function creates a new list from a provided iterable, sorts it
>   and returns it.

Your particular problems with this feature come from a misunderstanding of good ways to create a set rather than a language misdesign.  As Lattyware [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9300029/381450), in Python versions 2.7 and later you can use a set literal `a = {1}` or do `a = set([1])` as per Sven Marnach's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9299947/381450).

Parenthetically, I like Ruby's convention of placing an exclamation point after methods that mutate objects, but I find Python's approach acceptable.

Answer (score 28):

The `add()` method adds an element to the set, but it does not return the set again -- it returns `None`.

```
a = set()
a.add(1)
```

or better

```
a = set([1])
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a horrible misdesign in Python. What do you think?

Comment: @Randomblue: I think if it were utterly confusing if `set.add()` returned the set again.  Why should it?  The convention is:  If it changes the object in place, it returns `None`.  If it creates a new object, it returns the new object.  Just the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: @RandomBlue:  I created an answer to respond to your followup question.

Answer (score 5):

Because `add()` is modifing your set in place returning `None`:

```
>>> empty = set()
>>> print(empty.add(1))
None
>>> empty
set([1])
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it that is relatively simple would be:

```
a = set()
a = set() | {1}
```

this creates a union between your set a and a set with 1 as the element

print(a) yields {1} then because a would now have all elements of both a and {1}

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
a = set()
a.add(1)
print a
```

Notice that you're assigning to `a` the result of *adding* `1`, and the `add` operation, as defined in Python, returns `None` - and that's what is getting assigned to `a` in your code.

Alternatively, you can do this for initializing a set:

```
a = set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

The add method updates the set, but returns None.

```
a = set()
a.add(1)
print a
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the value returned by `set().add(1)` to a. This value is `None`, as `add()` does not return any value, it instead acts in-place on the list.

What you wanted to do was this:

```
a = set()
a.add(1)
print(a)
```

Of course, this example is trivial, but Python does support set literals, so if you really wanted to do this, it's better to do:

```
a = {1}
print(a)
```

The curly brackets denote a set (although be warned, `{}` denotes an empty dict, not an empty set due to the fact that curly brackets are used for both dicts and sets (dicts are separated by the use of the colon to separate keys and values.)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to a = set() | {1} consider "in-place" operator:

```
a = set()
a |= {1}
```