# Python - Extending a list directly results in None, why?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append, extend

```
x=[1,2,3]
x.extend('a')
```

Output:

```
x is [1,2,3,'a']
```

But when I do the following:

```
[1,2,3].extend('a')
```

Output:

```
None
```

Why does extend work on a list reference, but not on a list?

## 2nd Part:

I found this because I was trying to append a listB to a listA while trying to extend listC to listB.

```
listA.append([listB[15:18].extend(listC[3:12])])
```

Supposing lists cannot be directly appended / extending.  What is the most popular work around form for resolving this issue?

Comment: `None` is the output of print statement , if you are using `print [1,2,3].extend('a')`. Because return type of `extend` is `None`

Comment: It is a convention in Python that methods that mutate sequences return `None`.  More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299919/add-number-to-set/9300257#9300257).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.extend` modifies the list in place and returns nothing, thus resulting in `None`. In the second case, it's a temporary list that is being extended which disappears immediately after that line, while in the first case it can be referenced via `x`.

> to append a listB to a listA while trying to extend listC to listB.

Instead of using `extend`, you might want to try this:

```
listA.append(listB[15:18] + listC[3:12])
```

Or do it in multiple simple lines with `extend` if you want to actually modify `listB` or `listC`.

Answer (score 0):

`extend` will extend list it self. Return type of that method is `None`

If you want to `union` 2 list and add that list to another list then you have to use another way to add.

```
listB[15:18] = listC[3:12]
listA.extend(listB)
```