# Using methods for lists vs. using methods for strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a quick question about an issue I discovered. In the Python shell I can write `test1 = "hello".upper()` and when I type `test1` I get `"HELLO"`, as expected. However, if I do something similar with a list, such as `test2 = ["hello", "world"].reverse()`, and I try to return test2, I get nothing; it is a "NoneType" with no value assigned to it. Why does this happen? Why can I make an assignment with a method acting on a string but I can't make an assignment when there is a method acting on a list?

Comment: In python strings are immutable, so `upper()` has to return a new string. Lists are mutable so many operations are done inplace, e.g. `reverse()`

Comment: @achampion, I believe that ALL methods on a list are done in place.

Comment: `List.__add__` creates a new list.

Comment: @Akavall Nope, `pop`, `index`, `count`, etc.

Comment: @MorganThrapp those all operate on the list in-place, e.g. `pop()` removes the item for the list being reference. (`index()` and `count()` don't modify anything)

Comment: [It is a convention in Python that methods that mutate sequences return `None`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9300257/1322401)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski except `pop()` :)

Comment: @achampion, good point. I need to change my statement to: out all standard methods on a list (not counting the one with leading and trailing double under-scores) no method returns a new list, if there is a list modification it is done inplace: `.append()`, `.extend()`, `.pop()`, `insert()`, `sort()`, `reverse()`, `remove()`.

Comment: Functional methods are language features instead of methods. In this case, the *enumerable* trait is accessed by the language's own `object[start, end, step]` construct and by the comprehensions `f(x) for x in enumerable if condition(x)`. Just like the *sortable* traint is accessed with the language's own `<` and `>` symbols.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because [`list.reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) reverses in place. This means it returns `None`, so when you do `test2 = ["hello", "world"].reverse()`, you're assigning the result of `.reverse()` (`None`) to `test2`.

Answer (score 2):

First, strings are immutable, while lists are mutable. This means you can change an existing list object:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> id(l)
140370614775608
>>> l.append(4)
>>> l
[1,2,3,4]
>>> id(l)
140370614775608
```

You cannot change a string object, however; you can only create a new string object using the first as a starting point.

```
>>> s1 = "hello"
>>> id(s1)
140370614929376
>>> s1.upper()
'HELLO'
>>> id(s1)
140370614929376
```

In Python, the convention is that a method either modifies an object and returns `None`, or returns a new, modified object while leaving the original alone.

Comment: See also from the Design and History of Python [Why doesn’t list.sort() return the sorted list?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you can sometimes do one thing with one object and not do something different with a different object is that different objects and different methods are different.  The documentation for each method says what it does.  You need to look at the documentation for the individual method you are using to see what it does.  There is no reason to assume that `someString.upper()` will work like `someList.reverse()`, because strings are not lists, and `upper` is not `reverse`.

Comment: The first sentence would make a perfect Coelho quote :)

Answer (score 1):

`.upper()` returns a new String object, on the contrary, `.reverse()` is a destructive method, which means that the receiver is changed forever.

For reversing a list you can use

```
test2 = ["hello", "world"][::-1]
```

which would work for strings too:

```
In [1]: test2 = ["hello", "world"][::-1]

In [2]: test2
Out[2]: ['world', 'hello']

In [3]: test2 = "world"[::-1]

In [4]: test2
Out[4]: 'dlrow'
```

Functional constructs are built into the language and not in methods.

Answer (score 1):

.upper() returns a new string, which you assign to test1. The string you operated on ("hello") is not modified. Indeed, it couldn't be since strings are immutable in Python.

.reverse() modifies in-place. That means the object ["hello", "world"] got modified. Unfortunately, you don't have a variable pointing to that object, so you can't see that.

This is a convention in Python. Functions that modify in-place return None, whereas functions that create a modified copy return that copy.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the answers here do a good explanation. I just want to add that if you wanted to do an assignment with `reverse`, you can actually use `reversed` like so:

```
test2 = list( reversed( ["hello", "world"] ) )
# Result: ['world', 'hello']
```

`sort` and `sorted` are similar in this respect.